# How can I choose a sub document to insert and update with a click function from the client side

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two collections, one is a `Posts` collection which has posts, with an `id`.

[image]

And the other is a `Sets` collection which has an **array** called **ArticleId** that can be updated by the user by inserting a post id from the Posts collection into it via a click function with the button **`toggle-addToSet.`**

The user Creates the Array called **ArticleId**, gives it a name and saves articles in it periodically. **Think Pinterest Boards or G+ collections.**

[image]

I have a button on the post item that when a user *clicks the icon,* all the Sets he has created come up in a dialogue and the user chooses which Set he want to save the post id into.

```
<template name="summeryArticle">
<li>
  <div class="row col s12 m7">
    <div class="card" id="cardId">
      <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <a href="/latestSingle/{{_id}}"><img src="{{better_featured_image.source_url}}"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h5 class=" truncate grey-text text-darken-4">{{title.rendered}}</h5>
        <a href="/latestSingle/{{_id}}">MORE</a> <a href="#modal2" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light" onclick="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#bottom-options')"><i class="waves-effect waves-teal small material-icons right">playlist_add</i></a>{{>
        likePartial}}{{> reblogPartial}}
        <!-- The modal below is what brings up all the sets the user has created so that the user can pick with set they wat to save the article in  -->
        <div id="modal2" class="modal bottom-sheet">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="row">
              {{#each set}}
              <div class="col s6 m6 addSet teal">
                <div class="card ">
                  <div class="card-image">
                    <span class="card-title cardSet">{{name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn toggle-addToSet" name="button">add Article Id to this Set!</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</template>
```

Graphically it looks like this
[image]

And when the user clicks the icon `modal-trigger` to bring up the Sets he created, it looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the user has three Sets, Lifestyle, Love, Business, they can choose to save the **posts id** into any one of those three.

## GOAL ##

I want to be able to choose a Set, **click** the add button of my chosen Set, and somehow **capture the post Id** of the current post in my foreach loop, and *insert* it into that via the click function, at the moment all I have is this

```
Template.summeryArticle.events({
  'click .toggle-addToSet': function(e, template) {
    var ob = this.id
    console.log(ob);
  }
});
```

and when I console log that, I just get the **Set id** instead of the *post id.*

### Question

- How can I capture the `post id` of the current post,
- Choose a Set of my liking, then insert the post id into my chosen set?

And if there is a better way to achieve this, please let me know.

---

### EDIT AFTER FEEDBACK

I did the second option like this

```
<template name="summeryArticle">
{{#let article=this}}
<li>
  <div class="row col s12 m7">
    <div class="card" id="cardId">
      <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <a href="/latestSingle/{{_id}}"><img src="{{better_featured_image.source_url}}"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h5 class=" truncate grey-text text-darken-4">{{title.rendered}}</h5>
        <a href="/latestSingle/{{_id}}">MORE</a> <a href="#modal2" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light" onclick="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#bottom-options')"><i class="waves-effect waves-teal small material-icons right">playlist_add</i></a>{{>
        likePartial}}{{> reblogPartial}}

        <!-- The modal below is what brings up all the sets the user has created so that the user can pick with set they wat to save the article in  -->

        <div id="modal2" class="modal bottom-sheet">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="row">
              {{#each set}}
              <div class="col s6 m6 addSet teal">
                <div class="card ">
                  <div class="card-image">
                    <span class="card-title cardSet">{{name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer">
                    {{#each s in set}}
                    <button type="button" class="btn toggle-addToSet" name="button" data-setid="{{s._id}}" articleid="{{article._id}}">add Article Id to this Set!</button> {{/each}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {{/each}}
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

{{/let}}
</template>
```

my helper is like this

```
Template.summeryArticle.events({
  'click .toggle-addToSet': function(e, template) {
    var ob = this
    console.log(ob);
    var sid = $(e.currentTarget).data('setid');
    var aid = $(e.currentTarget).data('articleid');
    console.log(sid);
    console.log(aid);
  }
});
```

However, this is what I'm getting.

[image]

and the log looks like this

[image]

where `7MgLCEnTWjXFRhLg6` is the Sets_id depending on which of the three buttons I clicked

---

### SECOND EDIT. CONTEXT

when i do this

```
<template name="summeryArticle">
{{#let article=_id}}
<li>
  <div class="row col s12 m7">
    <div class="card" id="cardId">
      <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <a href="/latestSingle/{{_id}}"><img src="{{better_featured_image.source_url}}"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h5 class=" truncate grey-text text-darken-4">{{title.rendered}}</h5>
        <a href="/latestSingle/{{_id}}">MORE</a> <a href="#modal2" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light" onclick="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#bottom-options')"><i class="waves-effect waves-teal small material-icons right">playlist_add</i></a>{{> likePartial}}{{> reblogPartial}}

<!-- The modal below is what brings up all the sets the user has created so that the user can pick with set they wat to save the article in  -->

        <div id="modal2" class="modal bottom-sheet">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="row">
              {{#each s in set}}
                <div class="col s6 m6 addSet teal">
                  <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <span class="card-title cardSet">{{name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">

                  <button type="button" class="btn toggle-addToSet" name="button" data-setid="{{s._id}}" articleid="{{article._id}}">add Article Id to this Set!</button>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    {{/each}}
              </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</li>
{{/let}}
</template>
```

I get this

[image]

What's going on here is that I have the articles organised in categories, so what's going on now is that the `article=_id`being captured is the last article in the category, no matter what articles I try to add, it's just one article being caught, and its always the one at the bottom. I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. One would be something like this:

I would but article id and set id to toggle-addToSet button's data-attributes:

```
<button type="button" class="btn toggle-addToSet" name="button" data-setid="SETID" data-articleid="ARTID">add Article Id to this Set!</button>
```

If you call your summeryArticle like this:

```
{{#each article in articles}}
 {{>summeryArticle article=article}}
{{/each}}
```

(another opotion is use `let`-helper:

```
<template name="summeryArticle">
{{#let article=this}}
...
{{/let}}
</template>
```

Then in your summeryArticle-template you can get article id in sets-loop:

```
{{#each s in set}}
                    <button type="button" class="btn toggle-addToSet" name="button" data-setid="{{s._id}}" articleid="{{article._id}}>add Article Id to this Set!</button>
{{/each}}
```

Then in template events:

```
Template.summeryArticle.events({   
 'click .toggle-addToSet': function(e, template) {
    var ob = this.id
    console.log(ob);
    var sid = $(e.currentTarget).data('setid');
    var aid = $(e.currentTarget).data('articleid');
    Sets.update({_id: sid}, {$addToSet: {ArticlesId: aid}});   
  } 
 });
```

**Note!**

This assumes you can update your collection directly from client side! Depending on your situation, but usually it is not recommended. Normally you should deny client side updates and use methods for updating collections:

```
Method.call('mymethd', sid, aid, function(e, r) {
 if (!e) { 
  console.log(r);
 } else {
  console.error(e);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @iiro I couldn't work out the first example, so I did the second one and this is what I got, please look at the EDIT in the question to see the results. Thank you

Comment: You have an inner loop. Replace this {#each set}} with this {#each s in set}} and remove inner loop. Try {{#let articleid=_id}} and change data-articleid

Comment: It's getting there! I'm still having a problem, each article I try to add, only the bottom article in the category in being captured. take a look at the second edit. Thank you again for your time

Comment: data-articleid="{{article}}" :)

Comment: Perfect! @iiro Thank you, friend.

Comment: please take a look at my question which involves adding this via meteor methods [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273891/updating-a-sub-document-through-meteor-methods-via-a-click-function-proving-prob) @iiro