# Updating a sub-document through meteor methods via a click function proving problematic

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a button `.toggle-addToSet` that captures two integers, `this.id` which is the current posts' id,  and `setid (sid)` which is an `_id` of a collection `Set` which the user has the ability to create as many as they want. The goal is updating a chosen `Set` of a given `_id` `sid` with `this.id`. It looks like this in the js

```
Template.latestSingle.events({
  'click .toggle-addToSet': function(e, template) {
    var ob = this.id
    console.log(ob);
    var sid = $(e.currentTarget).data('setid');
    Meteor.call('addingSets', ob, sid, function(error, user) {
      console.log(ob)
    });
  }
});
```

What's going on is that `ob` is the `id` of a single document in an array, this document is a post, so I'm capturing that post.

Within each post context is a modal which brings about a collection called **Sets** which has a sub-document array called `ArticleId` that can be updated by the user by, inserting `this.id` `(ob)` via the click function with the button `toggle-addToSet` as seen above.

The user Creates the `Set` with a title such as **Business** or **Lifestyle** and when they create it, they can save post ids in an array called `ArticleId` whenever they find a post they would like to add. Think **Pinterest Boards** or **G+ collections**.

`var sid = $(e.currentTarget).data('setid');` is the _id of each **Set** which the use selects to add an article into.

The idea is to add `this.id (ob)` into the chosen Set through that Set's _id `sid`. Each Set looks like this
[image]

So my methods is like this

```
Meteor.methods({

    addingSets: function(set, sid, ob) {
        console.log(sid);
        console.log(ob);
        Sets.update({
      _id: sid
    },
    {
      $addToSet: {

        ArticleId: ob
      }
    });
    }
});
```

However this is not working, I cannot seem to be able to update it. I can do it manually by typing it through a form, but when it comes to updating it via the click function, it's not working.

When I do `console.log(sid);` in my server, methods I get the correct Set `_id` in my terminal.
When I do `console.log(ob);` in my server, methods I get `unidentified` in my terminal. But in my client, it's logging the correct this.id so there is a disconnect somewhere and I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: Some error. See your method: function(set, sid, ob) {
        console.log(sid);
        console.log(ob); WHAT is the set param? Remove that. And you call with ob + sid but method expects sib +ob. See the order of params.

Comment: Thank you! @iiro this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra parameter in your `addingSets` method.

Currently you have addingSets: `function(set, sid, ob)` defined in the function.

When you're calling it from the client, you're doing it like so:

```
Meteor.call('addingSets', ob, sid, function(error, user) {...}
```

Notice that the function is expecting 3 parameters to be passed to it while you're giving it only 2. So in your case, `ob` gets mapped to `set`, and `sid` gets mapped to `sid` and since the 3rd param isn't being passed, it's undefined.

**Helper:**

```
Template.latestSingle.events({
  'click .toggle-addToSet': function(e, template) {
    var ob = this.id
    console.log(ob);
    var sid = $(e.currentTarget).data('setid');
    Meteor.call('addingSets', ob, sid, function(error, user) {
      console.log(ob)
    });
  }
});
```

**Server:**

```
Meteor.methods({

    addingSets: function(ob, sid) {
        console.log(sid);
        console.log(ob);
        Sets.update({
      _id: sid
    },
    {
      $addToSet: {

        ArticleId: ob
      }
    });
    }
});
```

The positions and the params passed are important.